# Remove duplicates but keep first instance

Tags: awk, sed, csv

Please help me to resolve this issue from a csv file. AWK or Sed.

```
id1,ipadd1,number1
id1,ipadd2,number2
id1,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
id2,ipadd2,number2
id2,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
id3,ipadd2,number2
```

Desired output:

```
id1,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
ipadd2,number2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} seen[$1]++{$1=""} 1' file
id1,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number2
```

Comment: This uses the added assumption a seen 1st field should never be seen again. This is not stated in the question, but it _appears_ to be a correct assumption for the given data and output. It's unfortunately unclear whether "duplicate" means "duplicate anywhere" or "duplicated from previous record".  I took another approach in my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's weird that this morning I got 3 upvotes and a comment on an answer I posted 2 years ago. Any idea what's going on to make this question become active today?

Comment: :-) Possibly my fault. I added my own answer to the question after searching for related things.  This bumped it on the front page.  Then I read your answer. I seldom look at dates or user names when I answer or comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah, I see, that must be for people who order their front page by "Active", mine's always by "Newest" so that didn't occur to me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Posix sed:

```
sed -e '
  x;G
  /^\([^,]\{1,\}\),.*\n\1,/!{
    g;b
  }
  g;s/^[^,]\{1,\}//
' file
```

---

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=, '
  prev != $1 {
    print
    prev = $1
    next
  }
  {$1=""}1
' file
```

Output:

```
id1,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller to read the input as a set of header-less CSV records and to empty the first field in each record if it's equal to the previous record's first field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put 'if (FNR == 1 || $1 != @prev) { @prev = $1 } else { $1 = "" }' file
id1,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number2
```

The above only modifies the current record if the *previous* record's first field is the same as the current record's first field.  If the data is sorted, this has the effect of clearing *all* duplicated first fields.  If the data is unsorted, it only has a local effect.

The equivalent `awk` code, but only with support for "simple" CSV data (no fields with embedded delimiters or newlines):

```bash
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} { if (FNR == 1 || $1 != prev) prev = $1; else $1 = "" }; 1' file
id1,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd3,number3
id2,ipadd1,number1
,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number3
id3,ipadd2,number2
,ipadd2,number2
```